# Cannot find module '@react-navigation/native' or its corresponding type declarations

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, react-native

Im having trouble im my react-native app using expo and typescript. I have installed the libraries using npm and they are available in the `node_modules` folder see the picture.
[image]

The same problem is happening for `'@react-navigation/stack'`
and when I run the program I get this error:

```
 Error: Looks like you have nested a 'NavigationContainer' inside another. Normally you need only one container at the root of the app, so this was probably an error. If this was intentional, pass 'independent={true}' explicitely. Note that this will make the child navigators disconnected from the parent and you won't be able to navigate between them.
```

however my program have only one NavigationContainer. What seems to be the problem here ?
P.S: I tried reinstalling the packages but still no progress.

Comment: Can you show where you render your NavigationContainer? Are you sure there isn't more than one?

Answer (score 6):

To solve these errors: `Cannot find module X or its corresponding type declarations` run:

```
yarn add @types/X -D
```

in your case: `yarn add @types/@react-navigation/native @types/react-query -D`

This will install type definitions for these libraries, if available.